# Using Group Join return Key Value Pair

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I have two lists and would like to return as `Dictionary<UnitModel, IList<Model>>`

When I use GroupJoin, it returns `IEnumerable<Dictioanry<UnitModel,IList<Model>>>`

```
modelList.GroupJoin(unitList, i => i.UnitId, u => u.Id, (u, i) => new Dictionary<UnitModel, IList<Model>>
            {

            });
```

I was hoping if anyone knows how to use GroupJoin or any other way to return Dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
modelList.GroupJoin(unitList, i => i.UnitId, u => u.Id, (u, i) => new { u, i }).ToDictionary(g => g.u, g => g.i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var elements = modelList.GroupJoin(unitList, i => i.UnitId, u => u.Id, (u, i) => new KayValuePair<UnitModel, IList<Model>>
{

});
var list = elements.ToList(); //execute
var result = new Dictionary<UnitModel, IList<Model>>(list);
```

So, intead of returning a `Dictionary`, you use the list of `KeyValuePair` to construct it. If you want to return a `Dictionary` from LinQ, you need to use the `.ToDictionary()` method.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but when you do .ToList() it's still going to return it as list and when you pass that to Dictionary, it won't work as it will be expecting Dictionary and we are passing a list?

Comment: I believe this does solve the problem as well: https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/grouping-data-with-linq-and-mvc.html

Comment: @user1932923, GroupJoin returns a IEnumerable, you can use that in the constructor of the Dictionary. Otherwise, you need to use .GroupBy and then ToDictionary